# What is the proper use of inline assembly revert, and how do I retrieve returndata passed to it?

Tags: solidity, web3js, testrpc, assembly

I stumbled on [this EIP](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/206/files) which describes the `revert` opcode that looks like it allows you to "throw" more specific errors by passing a memory pointer with the opcode (also described briefly [in the docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/assembly.html#opcodes)). *Note in the docs that `return` and `revert` receive the same input format.*

So far, I have this function as an example:

```
function throwError(bytes _error) constant returns (bytes32) {
    assembly {
        calldatacopy(0xff, 0, calldatasize)
        return(add(0xff, 68), 32)
    }
}
```

It works as expected, copying the string passed as function parameter and returning it. However, when I change `return` to `revert` like this:

```
function throwError(bytes _error) constant returns (bytes32) {
    assembly {
        calldatacopy(0xff, 0, calldatasize)
        revert(add(0xff, 68), 32)
    }
}
```

All I get back is a normal `invalid opcode` error from web3, truffle, and remix when testing with testrpc. I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work; is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`revert` is not yet implemented in the EVM so it does indeed currently result in an invalid opcode (it's genuinely an invalid op-code in this case, not a proxy for `throw`). It will be part of the [Metropolis update](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/14726).

Comment: The feature is listed in release [0.4.10](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.10): `Inline assembly: Support revert (EIP140) as an opcode.`

Comment: Yes, the correct revert opcode is inserted by the compiler, 0xfd, but the EVM doesn't recognise it yet, so it barfs and will continue to do so until the first Metropolis fork.

Comment: Ohh that's interesting. Thanks for that clarification or I would've been trying to debug this for hours!

Comment: is there any updated on this issue?
does opcode revert exist with full capabilities?

Comment: Yes, `REVERT` was implemented in the [Byzantium](https://github.com/axic/EIPs/blob/348a79b7c5a0b7548c0abddbb5ac3a53889a59c7/EIPS/eip-609.md) fork and works fine.  However, current Solidity does not implement the ability to handle the data returned by Revert (the revert reason). This should be available Real Soon Now (maybe even is as an experimental feature. I'm too lazy to check).